# Ubuntu 21.10 is not waking up from lock or suspend on Dell Laptop

Tags: 21.10

I have recently upgraded my system from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 21.10. After upgrade I have observed an issue. The system is showing blank screen while locked or suspened. On mouse click or enter press it is not responding reulting to each time a restart. I have changed the screensaver from Gnome to xscreensaver, but nothing changed in behaviour. My system details are as follows:

[image: Hardware Details]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by installing lightdm login manager. I upgraded to Ubuntu 21.10 and encountering the blank screen issue while system was locked.

The default Ubuntu login screen is called lightdm. Chances are it's already installed in your system. So you can just run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` to re-select it. If it isn't installed, just run `sudo apt-get install lightdm` and then follow the commands in the wizard. If you want to uninstall the other login screen (really a display manager), write down the other choices that show up when you run the reconfigure command.

For me **gdm3** was already installed, so the installation wizard wanted to confirm which login manager to use by default, where I choose **lightdm**.

That's all.